# Program runs but produces no output when printing

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

I'm trying to build a standalone application like the dice roller on Roll20.net, starting off simple and as I get better I can add more features, including a GUI, but returning to this project after giving up months ago, I still cannot get even the most basic form to even output.

```
import random
from random import randint

d20 = randint(1,20)

str1 = "You rolled a "
str2 = "Congrats Critical Hit"
str3 = "Uh Oh, Critical Fail"

def roll(d20):
    roll(d20)
    print (str1 + roll(d20))

    if (d20 == 1):
        print (str3)

    elif (d20 == 20):
        print (str3)

    else:
        print ("")
```

I either get a completely blank output, implying that the program technically runs, or I'll get a "function roll at 0x02A3B078" or I'll get a response that something isn't defined.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You're defining a function, but not calling it? Add this line at the bottom of your program:

   ```
   roll(d20)
   ```
2. Don't call your function inside itself. This leads to infinite recursion.

---

What you need is something like this:

```
...

def roll(d20):
    print(str1, d20)

    if d20 == 1:
        print(str3)    
    elif d20 == 20:
        print(str3)

roll(d20)
```

---

Do you want to make your program interactive? You could initialise a `while` loop and repeat while as long as the user is interested in playing.

```
while True:
    d20 = randint(1, 20)
    roll(d20)

    if input('Keep playing? ') not in {'y', 'Y'}:
        break
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I tried your suggestion but now I'm getting the "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded" error, which I don't understand as I'm calling the function outside of the function? so I shouldn't be receiving such an error. Or have I just completely got this wrong?
About the interaction, my plan was to create a GUI at some point, where by pressing a button within the GUI calls the dice rolling function

Comment: @Tedwyn You're calling the function more than once buddy. Did you copy my code as is?

Comment: @Tedwyn I would recommend copying my code word for word or pasting your updated solution in the question so we can debug this together.

Comment: Copying it did the trick thank you very much, I originally had just typed it, I'm not sure what was causing the issue as the indentation looked correct

Answer (score 0):

Try that

```
import random
from random import randint

str1 = "You rolled a "
str2 = "Congrats Critical Hit"
str3 = "Uh Oh, Critical Fail"

def roll(d20):

    print (str1 + str(d20))

    if (d20 == 1):
        print (str3)

    elif (d20 == 20):
        print (str3)


num_of_rolls = 10    
while num_of_rolls:
    d20 = randint(1,20)
    roll(d20)
    num_of_rolls -= 1
```

Some things that you may take into account in the future. You didn't call the function. It sometimes prints no output, because it has 18:20 chance to `print("")`. You shouldn't start with `(1,20)` range. Test `(1,2)` and put `print` statement everywhere you can. That's the only way to be sure what's happening inside your function. You don't need to `print("")` if you don't need it.

Comment: Thank you for the response, the test range was something I had completely overlooked for testing, much appreciated

Comment: @Tedwyn No problem. Good luck